# How to write program for excel VBA loop files in a folder and find specific text in cells and save the file in another folder if it match to condition

Tags: excel, vba

For example there are some files in folder, loop files in folder and it should search specific text in specified cells if text matches with cells file should save in specified path

```
This line am getting error"If Range("A6").Value = ("CORE SKUS ONLY: N").Value  & If Range("A7").Value =("ECO SKUS ONLY: Y").Value Then
```

{{{{Sub OpenLatestFile()

```
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = "CORE SKUS ONLY"

    Dim LMD As Date
MyPath = "C:\Users\p_Divyanka\Desktop\Divyanka\Vendor Metrics\US"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "RptLineItemFillRate_*.xls", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
     MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
     Exit Sub
End If

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
If LMD > LatestDate Then
LatestFile = MyFile
LatestDate = LMD
End If
MyFile = Dir
Loop
Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
Windows("RptLineItemFillRate_*.xls").Activate
ActiveWindow
    If Range("A6").Value = ("CORE SKUS ONLY: N").Value  & If Range("A7").Value =("ECO SKUS ONLY: Y").Value Then
    Windows("RptLineItemFillRate_*.xls").Activate
    ChDir "C:\Users\p_Divyanka\Desktop\Divyanka\Vendor Metrics\US\FY2018\ING"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\p_Divyanka\Desktop\Divyanka\Vendor Metrics\US\FY2018\ING\US_ING_Aged_Detail.xls" _
        , FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Else
    ActiveWindow.Close
    End If
    End Sub}}}}
```

Comment: What's exactly the issue? Please, describe your problem with more detail..

Comment: You want to remove the second `IF` in the problem line. In VBA, the `IF` and `Then` are "markers" for the application to identify the conditions. Having two `IF`'s before one `THEN` is confusing the application. Also, for logical conditions use `AND` instead of `&`. `&` is primarily used for concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is VBS so is paste able into VBA.

```
'Remove next line in VBA
Main

Sub Main
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dirname = InputBox("Enter Dir name (don't use quotes)")
    Searchterm = Inputbox("Enter search term")
    ProcessFolder DirName
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
'   On Error Resume Next
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Set Fls = fldr.files
    For Each thing in Fls
            If Instr(LCase(thing.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll), LCase(SearchTerm)) > 0 then
            msgbox Thing.Name & " " & Thing.path 
            'fso.copyfile thing.path, "C:\backup"
        End If
    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing in fldrs
        ProcessFolder thing.path
    Next
End Sub
```