# In VBA is there a loop type, function, or way to clean up nested For Each loops of Nodes in HTML file?

Tags: vba, dom, foreach, nodes, nested-loops

Trying to find a way to simplify multiple For Each loops.  When I start using adding code to actually do something with he data parsed I realized this is going to take some work.

I already have something working using Internet Explorer reference but my goal is to not use any extra references as it is faster.  Also hope to use this on a Mac one day.  I am coding in Excel to see what I get as I am working on it.  The final will actually be in PowerPoint.

```
Sub TestHTML()
    'Load Document
    Set objDocument = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    objDocument.async = False: objDocument.validateOnParse = False
    objDocument.Load (ThisWorkbook.Path & "ThisFile.html")
    Set ZeroNode = objDocument.DocumentElement
    'Set Rows and Columns
    intRow = 0
    intColAttribute = 1
    intColTag = 2
    intColText = 3
    'Loop through Nodes
    For Each OneNode In ZeroNode.ChildNodes
        If OneNode.HasChildNodes() Then
            For Each TwoNode In OneNode.ChildNodes
                If TwoNode.HasChildNodes() Then
                    For Each ThreeNode In TwoNode.ChildNodes
                        If ThreeNode.HasChildNodes() Then
                            For Each FourNode In ThreeNode.ChildNodes
                                If FourNode.HasChildNodes() Then
                                    For Each FiveNode In FourNode.ChildNodes
                                        If FiveNode.HasChildNodes() Then
                                            For Each SixNode In FiveNode.ChildNodes
                                                If SixNode.HasChildNodes() Then
                                                    For Each SevenNode In SixNode.ChildNodes
                                                        intRow = intRow + 1
                                                        If SixNode.Attributes.Length > 0 Then Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColAttribute) = SixNode.Attributes(0).Text
                                                        Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColTag) = SevenNode.BaseName
                                                        Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColText) = SevenNode.Text
                                                    Next SevenNode
                                                Else 'SixNode.HasChildNodes()
                                                    intRow = intRow + 1
                                                    If FiveNode.Attributes.Length > 0 Then Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColAttribute) = FiveNode.Attributes(0).Text
                                                    Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColTag) = SixNode.BaseName
                                                    Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColText) = SixNode.Text
                                                End If 'SixNode.HasChildNodes()
                                            Next SixNode
                                        Else 'FiveNode.HasChildNodes()
                                            intRow = intRow + 1
                                            If FourNode.Attributes.Length > 0 Then Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColAttribute) = FourNode.Attributes(0).Text
                                            Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColTag) = FiveNode.BaseName
                                            Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColText) = FiveNode.Text
                                            End If 'FiveNode.HasChildNodes()
                                    Next FiveNode
                                Else 'FourNode.HasChildNodes()
                                    intRow = intRow + 1
                                    If ThreeNode.Attributes.Length > 0 Then Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColAttribute) = ThreeNode.Attributes(0).Text
                                    Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColTag) = FourNode.BaseName
                                    Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColText) = FourNode.Text
                                End If 'FourNode.HasChildNodes()
                            Next FourNode
                        Else 'ThreeNode.hasChildNode()
                            intRow = intRow + 1
                            If TwoNode.Attributes.Length > 0 Then Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColAttribute) = TwoNode.Attributes(0).Text
                            Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColTag) = ThreeNode.BaseName
                            Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColText) = ThreeNode.Text
                        End If 'ThreeNode.hasChildNode()
                    Next ThreeNode
                Else 'TwoNode.hasChildNode()
                        intRow = intRow + 1
                        If OneNode.Attributes.Length > 0 Then Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColAttribute) = OneNode.Attributes(0).Text
                        Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColTag) = TwoNode.BaseName
                        Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColText) = TwoNode.Text
                End If 'TwoNode.hasChildNode()
            Next TwoNode
        Else 'OneNode.hasChildNode()
                intRow = intRow + 1
                Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColTag) = OneNode.BaseName
                Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColText) = OneNode.Text
        End If 'OneNode.hasChildNode()
    Next OneNode
    Set objDocument = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is an example HTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta content="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
  <body class="c0">
<div class="sheader" id="c_pb_21">
<span class="snumber">1</span>
<span class="stitle">Title</span>
    <div class="sinfo">
    InfoLine1 <br class="c1"/>
    InfoLine2 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sbody">
<p class="left">Intro</p>
<dl class="v">
    <dt class="vnumber">1.</dt>
    <dd class="vbody">
    VLine1<br class="c1"/>
    VLine2<br class="c1"/>
    VLine3<br class="c1"/>
    VLine4<p class="c6"/>
<p class="c6">VLine6<br class="c1"/>
    VLine7<br class="c1"/>
    VLine8<br class="c1"/>
    VLine9</p>
<p class="c6">VLine11<br class="c1"/>
    VLine12<br class="c1"/>
    VLine13<br class="c1"/>
    VLine14<br class="c1"/>
    VLine15<br class="c1"/>
    VLine16</p></dd>
</dl>
<dl class="v">
    <dt class="vnumber">2.</dt>
    <dd class="vbody">
    VLine1<br class="c1"/>
    VLine2<br class="c1"/>
    VLine3<br class="c1"/>
    VLine4<p class="c6"/>
<p class="c6">VLine6<br class="c1"/>
    VLine7<br class="c1"/>
    VLine8<br class="c1"/>
    VLine9</p>
<p class="c6">VLine11<br class="c1"/>
    VLine12<br class="c1"/>
    VLine13<br class="c1"/>
    VLine14<br class="c1"/>
    VLine15<br class="c1"/>
    VLine16</p></dd>
</dl>
<dl class="v">
    <dt class="vnumber"> </dt>
    <dd class="cs">
    CLine1<br class="c1"/>
    CLine2<br class="c1"/>
    CLine3<br class="c1"/>
    CLine4</dd>
</dl>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Here is what I am trying to pull from this HTML:

```
snumber:        1
stitle:         Title
sinfo[Line1]:   InfoLine1
sinfo[Line2]:   InfoLine2 

left:           Intro
v[1](vnumber):  1
v[1](TYPE):     vbody      << TYPE is from the class name
v[1](Line1):    VLine1     << vbody is split at the <br class="c1"/>
v[1](Line2):    VLine2
v[1](Line3):    VLine3
v[1](Line4):    VLine4
v[1][1](Line1): VLine6     << <p class="c6"> needs to be identified, yet <dd class="vbody"> continues
v[1][1](Line2): VLine7
v[1][1](Line3): VLine8
v[1][1](Line4): VLine9
v[1][2](Line1): VLine11
v[1][2](Line2): VLine12
...
v[2][2](Line6): VLine16
v[3](vnumber):
v[3](TYPE):     cs         << TYPE is from the class name
v[3](Line1):    CLine1     
v[3](Line2):    CLine2
v[3](Line3):    CLine3
v[3](Line4):    CLine4
```

This code works, just trying to clean it up so I can work with it easier.

My ultimate goal is to make it so I can take multiple types of HTML files and 'convert' them to PowerPoint.  I have already done this for this example document another way.  This code has been helpful for seeing what can be pulled, but the next step of actually using the info is where it becomes hard.

I am relativity new to programming but have scripted many things.  This is my first time posting to a forum.

Comment: Can you add details about the construction of the HTML. Specifically, what do you know about the sixth and seventh child nodes: do they have specific IDs, classes, tag names, etc., as there are methods to retrieve nodes by those properties. Perhaps edit your question to include some sample HTML. Without that information, it's very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: Protip: **recursive functions** (and `QuerySelectorAll`).

Comment: Some of the Child nodes I pull the info at the 4th level other at the 7th.  The tag names, nor the classes are consistent.

Comment: I am open to new idea's of how to accomplish this, yet I also want to know if there is a better way to do loops in general.  Even if I get pointed to some training material about loops and when to use them where.

Comment: Recursion walks trees not loops. Loops do lists.

Comment: Most programs use a maximum of two loops at a time, like comparing two files. The System Browser uses https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms536439(v=vs.94). There are same named methods in XMLDOM, Windows Forms etc. Note this is a collection or a list of objects with that tag name. So one loop. `For Each` loops are easier to program than `For x = n to n` loops.

Comment: @Noodles Thanks for your comments, I will be looking into Recursion walks trees.

Comment: @Ambie I updated the questions with sample code.  Tag names, nor class are consistent.  Neither is the level at which the content is found.

Comment: See an example searching files in a tree https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640444/how-to-write-program-for-excel-vba-loop-files-in-a-folder-and-find-specific-text and for searching the registry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026790/searching-the-registry-with-vbs-to-find-an-unknown-part-of-the-path

Comment: It's still not clear to me what data you are trying to acquire. Can you somehow indicate what data items you're after - and if you can't be sure where they would be in the xml structure, is there anything consistent about the data items themselves?

Comment: @Noodles Thanks again :) Off topic what is the -2 next to the question mean on the link you posted?  The next link you shared has a 1 next to the question.

Comment: @Ambie Thanks for your attempt to help me :) I see what you mean now by being unclear.  I believe Noodles answered my question about loops by pointing me to Trees.  I will add the specifics I am looking for these html files.  Maybe I should reword the question as I am looking for the best way so I can modify the code easily for my next project.  I will comment again once it's added so you can take a look again.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh826020(v=vs.94) (or the similar `childnodes` collection) using recursion.

Comment: Thanks again @Noodles, I believe this will help me with all my future programming. :)

Comment: @Ambie Thanks again for your willingness to help.  I added a code block of what info I am trying to pull.  I hope this clarifies.  Be aware this info is pulled so I can reformat the HTML in PowerPoint, which is why I keep as much info as possible.  My current plan is to use the info Noodles gave me and post an answer once I have a re-write of the code.

Comment: @Noodles Thanks for the assistance.  Once I understand Recursion more I think I will post another question about this.  I found an answer to my question, still using loops.  I think I am going to buy a book on VB, any suggestions?

Comment: Here's the spec for writing your own VBA language https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx. The VBS help file is applicable to VBA as well http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe and a book http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwixyY_LnIXiAhXNX30KHZ6jBjoQFjAEegQIBRAC&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.borg.moe%2Fyarr%2FGentoomen%2520Library%2FProgramming%2FMisc%2FOReilly.Vb.%26%2520Vba%2520Nutshell.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1C6umeWyQgONYrsEK71bTQ

Comment: I also have sample programs here https://pastebin.com/u/dcandygmailcom and its new home https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was originally trying to do.  When doing some more research I found an example of someone traversing file folders.  What I learned from that is that a sub could call itself.  This makes it possible to clean up the code.  See the code below:

```
Public intRow As Integer
Public intColAttribute As Integer
Public intColTag As Integer
Public intColText As Integer

Sub TestHTML()
    'Load Document
    Set objDocument = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    objDocument.async = False: objDocument.validateOnParse = False
    objDocument.Load (ThisWorkbook.path & "\ThisFile.html")
    Set ParentNode = objDocument.DocumentElement
    'Set Rows and Columns
    intRow = 1
    intColAttribute = 1
    intColTag = 2
    intColText = 3
    'Loop through Nodes
    If Not ParentNode Is Nothing Then
      TraverseNodes ParentNode
    End If 'Not ParentNode
End Sub

Sub TraverseNodes(ParentNode)
    For Each ChildNode In ParentNode.ChildNodes
      If ChildNode.HasChildNodes() Then
        TraverseNodes ChildNode
      Else 'ChildNode.HasChildNodes()
        intRow = intRow + 1
        Debug.Print intRow
        If ParentNode.Attributes.Length > 0 Then
          ' Here is where I can decide what to do with the Class Name
          Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColAttribute) _
            = ParentNode.Attributes(0).Text
        End If 'ParentNode.Attributes.Length
        ' Here is where I can decide what to do with the Tag Name and Text
        Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColTag) = ChildNode.BaseName
        Worksheets("Test").Cells(intRow, intColText) = ChildNode.Text
      End If 'ChildNode.HasChildNodes()
    Next ChildNode
End Sub
```

Comment: And that is a lot simpler.